# React JW player how to get current duration of video?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jwplayer

I am using [React JW player](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-jw-player).

My component

```
                    <ReactJWPlayer
                      playerId="id"
                      playerScript="https://content.jwplatform.com/libraries/xxxx.js"
                      playlist={{"My JSON"}}
                    />
```

This is working well. I need to get the current duration of the playing video. How can I do that in reactjs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access "raw" JW player by doing

```js
<ReactJWPlayer playerId="id" ...

let playerInstance = window.jwplayer('id');
```

---

To get current position of JW Player do

```js
playerInstance.getPosition();
```

[Expose JW Player instance](https://github.com/micnews/react-jw-player/issues/20) | [JW Player .getPosition()](https://developer.jwplayer.com/jwplayer/docs/jw8-javascript-api-reference#jwplayergetposition)

Comment: You nailed it man... Awesome :-)

Comment: Hi Justinas, I need to play the video on page load(as soon as it loads the video). How can I do that?